# Create table in SQL while renaming fields in a record (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, record

I am trying to create a new table in my datawarehouse, I need to rename the fields.
I am using BigQuery for this
The fields in the base table and their types are as follows:

```
created       STRING
fields_count  INTEGER   
fields_type   STRING        
fields_data   RECORD 
value         STRING    
label         STRING
```

I am not sure how to go about flattening the records from the table in order to be able create the new sturcture

Comment: Please share your dbms name and structures of your new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sql server then:

```
select created new_created, fields_count new_fields_count ,fields_type new_fields_type, fields_data new_fields_data, [value] new_value, label new_label into newtable from oldtable
```

Above sql will create newtable from oldtable with column names prefixed by **new_**

For BigQuery:

```
Create table newtable
as select created new_created, fields_count new_fields_count ,fields_type new_fields_type, fields_data new_fields_data, [value] new_value, label new_label  from oldtable
```

Comment: I am using BigQuery .